# Understanding standard c++ inline assembly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly

I'm trying to port this inline assembly to mcvc:

```
asm("cmpl %3, %2\n\tcmovg %4, %0\n\tcmovle %5, %1"
    : "+r" (begin), "+r" (end)
    : "r" (x), "g" (key), "g" (middle + 1), "g" (middle));
```

Is this pseudocode below correctly implements assembly above?

```
if key > x:
    begin = middle + 1
else:
    end = middle
```

Comment: at&t has operands reversed so you got the condition wrong, it should be `x > key`

Comment: I assume you mean standard gnu inline assembly, since standard c++ inline assembly doesn't exist.  Also, your pseudocode computes `middle+1` only if needed, while the inline asm tells the compiler 'middle+1` should be computed unconditionally.

Comment: @JSF Does it affect result if operator + has no side effects and its result goes to nowhere if condition not met?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that would affect the result.  Mainly I meant to imply this doesn't look like the kind of situation in which inline assembly is useful (as compared to just letting the optimizer decide).